# In Rails, how can you use a .where('rooms.id not in (?), ____), when ____ doesn't return anything?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :layout
  has_many :visits

  validates :number, presence: true
  validates :rate, presence: true
  #validates :smoking, presence: true

  def self.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date) #24-26
    self.joins(:visits).where('date >= ? and date <= ?', from_date, to_date).uniq
  end

  def self.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date)
    self.where('rooms.id not in (?)', Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date).select(:id).to_a)
  end

  def self.find_rooms_with(occupancy_count, smoking, from_date, to_date)
    Room.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date).joins(:layout).where('occupancy_count >= ?',     occupancy_count).where('smoking = ?', smoking)
  end  
end
```

method vacant_rooms does not work, when occupied rooms returns nothing.

For example, let say a room is booked Apr 29th. And we want to find occupied rooms between Apr 28-30. It till return out occupied room. Vacant_rooms will returns all rooms but our one booked room.

However, if we try and find vacant_rooms between May 1-3 for example, it won't return anything, because occupied rooms is not returning anything and it does not like...

```
self.where('rooms.id not in (?)', Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date).select(:id).to_a)
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very nice thing that got introduced in Rails 4 called a `WhereChain`. You can use it like this:

```
self.where.not(id: Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date).select(:id))
```

Though I'm pretty sure it can be even simpler with:

```
self.where.not(id: Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date))
```

Comment: @chris P Could you accept it as an answer? It'll then get moved out of those search filters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
self.where('rooms.id not in (?)', Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date).select(:id).to_a.join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  def self.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date)
    occupied_rooms = Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date).select(:id).to_a
    self.where('rooms.id not in (?)', occupied_rooms.present? ? occupied_rooms : "")
  end
```

If `occupied_rooms` returns an empty array then `not in` condition would be checked against `""` (empty string) so it will return all the records.

Alternatively, you could directly use `id` in the query instead of `rooms.id` as you are querying single table `rooms` in this query.

```
self.where('id not in (?)', occupied_rooms.present? ? occupied_rooms : "")
```